# Power App Custom Connector: Cannot call CRM function RetrieveRolePrivilegesRole

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps

My swagger JSON for the custom connector looks like below:

```
"/roles({roleid})/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RetrieveRolePrivilegesRole": {
      "post": {
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Success Operation"
          }
        },
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "roleid",
            "in": "path",
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
          }
        ],
        "operationId": "_POST_RetrieveRolePrivilegesRole",
        "description": "Retrieve Role Privileges",
        "summary": "Retrieve Role Privileges"
      }
    },
```

When I create a custom connector with this and test the call, I am getting following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "0x0",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RetrieveRolePrivilegesRole'",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.RetrieveRolePrivilegesRole'",
      "type": "Microsoft.Crm.CrmHttpException",
      "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.Routing.CrmODataRoutingConvention.ThrowUnresolvedSegmentException(ODataPath odataPath)\r\n   at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ODataV4.Routing.CrmODataRoutingConvention.SelectActionImplementation(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext controllerContext, ILookup`2 actionMap)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerApps.CoreFramework.ActivityLoggerExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, EventId eventId, ActivityType activityType, Func`1 func, IEnumerable`1 additionalCustomProperties)\r\n   at Microsoft.Xrm.Telemetry.XrmTelemetryExtensions.Execute[TResult](ILogger logger, XrmTelemetryActivityType activityType, Func`1 func)\r\n   at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that means the role_id variable is not a valid GUID for the RolePrivilegesRole entity. To get  a list of valid guids you can retreive them from the RolePrivileges entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/roleprivileges?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9

Comment: @Jon Looks like the RetrieveRolePrivilegesRole is an unbound action. So we have to call it directly without appending with any entity path. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Hey, glad you figured it out. For my own benefit, I am curious to see the full solution. You should answer your own question to show how it worked!